# How to set autofocus on Laravel input field using Form::text whilst still setting the class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I can't seem to set autofocus on a input field in Laravel 5.4, whilst also setting the class of the element.

What I've tried:

```
{{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email'), ['class'=>'field-Login'], array('autofocus'=>'autofocus'))}}

{{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email'), array('autofocus'=>'autofocus'), ['class'=>'field-Login'])}}

{{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email'), array('autofocus'=>'autofocus',['class'=>'field-Login']))}}
```

Comment: Ahh yes! @Crawdingle

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine your attributes. For example:

```
echo Form::text('email', 'default@value.com', ['class' => 'class123', 'autofocus']);
```